# Natural continental isolation in the form of a long string of cliffs?

Tags: internal-consistency, geography, topography

In my worldbuilding there's a planet with a continental population, that was until a certain period of time unknown for the rest of the world. The continent in question is positioned in such a way that at the south-western intersection point with the other continent there is a massive desert (largest one on the whole planet in fact), and it is inaccessible from the sea since the whole northern edge consists of sheer cliffs up to half a kilometer in height, almost devoid of any openings that would allow people to reach inside the continent, or shores and islands on which an outpost settlement could be established.
[image]
(The red line shows the extent of the cliff)

So, something like that, but about twice as tall and stretching for thousands of kilometers:
[image]

The question is, does having that long uninterrupted stretch of sheer cliff is plausible, and would it help with preventing the exploration of that region of the planet until the seafaring technology would become good enough to sail around it (On this planet, the oceans are also home for several species of what can only be called "sea monsters", so sailing for long distances is perilous on its own)?

Comment: uninterrupted is going to be difficult rivers will cut accessible outlets

Comment: If that continent is inaccessible... where did the population come from?

Comment: Presumably, the climate was different back then, and the desert wasn't as large or as hot as it is nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Such a long stretch of cliff is not plausible. At least not without occasional breaks. Assuming the land above was desert then it might be slightly more convincing (although not much). The reason being if there is rain in the areas then chances are there will be rivers, weathering and erosion.

At least some of the water will find it's way back to the sea somewhere along the coast by way of a river valley. the land might all slope the other way, but the greater the length of coast the less plausible this becomes.

Even in your picture the headland in the distance, although no doubt formidable looks a lot easier to climb than those in the foreground and a determined, reckless and skilled climber could probably find some where to get up.

Also the higher the cliff the more susceptible it is to erosion and the more specialist are the conditions for its creation.

Answer (score 2):

The longest stretch of sea cliffs in the word are on the south coast of Australia along the Great Australian Bight. The conditions there are ideal in that the climate is dry and drainage tends to be away from the coast toward the north, and yet the single longest uninterrupted stretch, the [Bunda Cliffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunda_cliffs), don't go further than 100 kilometers or so.

Uninterrupted cliffs stretching for thousands of kilometers is, as mentioned, not plausible.

Answer (score 1):

Persistent cliffs form in only a few basic fashions.

In Ontario, Canada, the Niagara Escarpment is a cliff that extends from Niagara Falls to Tober Mory. That is Lake Ontario at the bottom, and the Bruce Peninsula at the top, poking into Georgian Bay. The wiggly green path shows the cliff edge.

[image]

It is some 100's of km long, averaging about 180 feet high. In some locations it is next to lake, here Georgian Bay.

[image]

It persists because it is several layers of rock, with the softest layer at the bottom. So it erodes at the bottom first. This causes the cliff face to be undercut rather than erode from the top. When a section is undercut enough it breaks off the cliff, forming a fresh new face. The rubble then is broken into smaller chunks that erode away comparably much faster. You can see the this process at work here, there being hollows into the cliff at the water line.

The problem with this is, whenever a chunk does break off it makes a, possibly temporary, ramp to the top. So even though the feature persists there are nearly always a lot of easily climbed ramps. The Bruce Trail is a hiking trail that follows not too far from the cliff. It goes up or down the cliff many times, and most of the time using naturally occurring features.

[image]

This is one very pretty place where this has happened, Albion Falls. The rubble has collected and formed a very pretty terrace effect.

[image]

Another means to produce a persistent cliff is geologic uplift or subsidence. One part of the crust is moving vertically relative to the next. A stunning example is the [Great Rift Valley in Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Rift_Valley).  This does produce some stupendous cliffs.

[image]

And these do persist for geologically significant periods. But even in this case, there is nearly always a nearby ramp. Indeed, if you look closely, there is farmland part way down.

[image]

In other words, it is very difficult to have an impassible cliff remain so over more than a few km for any length of time. It is entirely likely that some part of it will collapse or erode to form a ramp.